# Calling jsp inside a servlet with another new parameter

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I have a jsp (**items.jsp**) which iterate product list and display result products.In its scrip-let I iterate the products list like below:

```
<jsp:useBean id="items" scope="page" class="com.certus.controllers.ItemPage"/>

<%
  List<Product> products = null;

   //check if the parameter "sort" available or not
    if (request.getParameter("sort") != null) {
        System.out.print("Three parameter method");
        products = items.filterProducts(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sub")),
                Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cat")),request.getParameter("sort"));
    } else {
        System.out.print("Two parameter method");
        products = items.filterProducts(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sub")),
                Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cat")));
    }
    for (Product p : products) {
%>

  some html content here....
```

Up to this stage everything works fine.In this same jsp I have a selectbox which I have introduced to sort the products as the client needs. Once I select an item from the selectbox it sends a request to the servlet and nothing wrong with that ajax request too. (Test with System.out.println() and got the required results from the glass-fish sever.)

From there on wards I came up with a problem. Here is my servlet :

```
     String category = request.getParameter("category");
        String sub = request.getParameter("sub_category");
        String sort = request.getParameter("sort");

//Tried with both methods but no luck
   //     response.sendRedirect("items.jsp?cat=" + category + "&sub="+ 
  //sub + "&sort=" + sort);

RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj = request.getRequestDispatcher("items.jsp?cat=" + category + "&sub=" + sub + "&sort=" + sort);
RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);
```

As you can see I'm trying to redirect to the items.jsp with another parameter included with the url (sort) to call the three para-metered method which was inside the items.jsp.

All the suggestions are welcome to figure out where I have made the mistake. In case you need my ajax call here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("change", "#sortCombo", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sortProducts',
            data: {category: $('#category').val(), sub_category: $('#sub_category').val(), sort: $('#sortCombo').val()},
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
               // alert(data);
                // $('#somediv').text(responseText);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
        );
    });
</script>
```

`sortProducts` is the servlet name.**And also need to tell you write on the url with sort parameter and refresh the page works fine and giving the required result which display products sorted by name,price ratings etc..** Thank you.

**UPDATE**

> If I can call the method(Three parameter one) by writing on the URL
>   why not the ajax response do the same with `response.sendRedirect("items.jsp?cat=" + category + "&sub=" + sub + "&sort=" + sort);` ???

Comment: Only response that redirects is a servlet response, you don't need to redirect if you are using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ,I came up with a solution. May be not the most appropriate one.  I changed my `servlet` code to:

```
        response.getWriter().write(category+"-"+sub+"-"+sort);
//        RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj = request.getRequestDispatcher("items.jsp");
//        RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);
```

And my `ajax success` to :

```
success: function (data) {
   var split = data.split("-");
   document.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/ECommerceApp/items.jsp?cat=" + split[0] + "&sub=" + split[1] + "&sort=" + split[2];
                },
```

Thank you every one who helped me even by a comment.They mean lot to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Setting Request Attributes in a Servlet

In your servlet, you can use [`ServletRequest.setAttribute(String, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to make them request attributes;

```
String category = request.getParameter("category");
String sub = request.getParameter("sub_category");
String sort = request.getParameter("sort");
request.setAttribute("category", category);
request.setAttribute("sub_category", sub);
request.setAttribute("sort", sort);
```

#### Reading Request Attributes in a JSP

then you can access them in your JSP with [**Expression Language**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html) [*Value Statements*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#bnahv) like

```
${requestScope.category}
${requestScope.sub_category}
```

and

```
${requestScope.sort}
```

Comment: So I have to use
 `RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj = request.getRequestDispatcher("items.jsp");
RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);`
 instead of 
`RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj = request.getRequestDispatcher("items.jsp?cat=" + category + "&sub=" + sub + "&sort=" + sort);
RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);` ??

Comment: @johndoe Yes. You *might* also be able to use [`include`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) (depending on what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: As you can see I just need to call the **three parameter method** inside the `items.jsp` which requires another parameter to sort the product list..

Comment: Yes. I did not go for EL . I use `request.getParameter("cat");`... etc.. Over three days I m dealing with this problem. Your help would be really appreciable.

Comment: Use `request.getAttribute` in the JSP and `request.setAttribute` in the Servlet You cannot use `request.getParameter` in the target JSP.

Comment: And `request.getAttribute("cat");`.. works as the same.. :(

Comment: Are you using `include` (or `forward`)? Next, you could try the session and the debugger.

Comment: Writing on URL `http://localhost:8080/ECommerceApp/items.jsp?cat=2&sub=5&sort=priceAsc` works well and displays the products sorted.  Isnt it possible to use parameters binding with the URL `request.getRequestDispatcher("items.jsp?cat=" + category + "&sub=" + sub + "&sort=" + sort);`  inside the servlet ??

Comment: Ok then why not `response.sendRedirect("items.jsp?cat=" + category + "&sub=" + sub + "&sort=" + sort);`. ??  Sorry If i bothering you...

Comment: Because the request parsing of http headers doesn't run again with `RequestDispatcher` methods.

Comment: My I know the way I have implemented this or the way I have approached to this is contrary to standards ???